# Constrain screen reader to only speak content from specific browsers / processes / tabs and not every application

Tags: accessibility, screen-reader

I am developer and new to screen readers. I am currently using NVDA and driving myself completely insane because of course it reads **everything** in every program I have open. This clogs my CPU because it's reading tonnes of unnecessary stuff.

As a result I have to continually mute the sound, quit and restarting NVDA as I incrementally add functionality over time. I need a better solution!

Is there a trick to getting a screenreader to work just with a single browser tab or process or to ignore certain apps? Do other (paid) screenreaders provide advanced functionality like this. Is there a Windows API handling all this?

I know NVDA has a text window where it reads text but this isn't really sufficient.

I'm trying hard to make my site as accessible as possible but the way I'm working now isn't sustainable for my sanity! Any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: I only have experience with Jaws (it has a free trial that works for 45 minutes). Once it gets to the browser content window it tends to stay there. I have a feeling that this is probably not going to be answerable here, are you able to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) about this?

Comment: I just tested the Windows 10 Narrator, it's actually pretty good. Would that solve your issues?